# In Anaconda, How to install packages in NON-ROOT environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, gis, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I am using my own environment called datascience in anaconda.
When I found that I need the Geopandas package and installed it using conda install, the Geopandas package was installed in the "root environment".
Is there any way to install packages directly to the environment or copying from the root environment to another?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using virtual Environments? That is the only way to isolate packages within one environment.  Your IDE might provide some easy tools to do this for you if not look into  [link](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation for the `conda install` command: https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-install.html and the tutorial on managing packages: https://conda.io/docs/using/pkgs.html#install-a-package

In short, you can specify the environment to install to in the install command

```
conda install -n env-name package-name
```

or you can activate the environment, then install

```
conda activate env-name
conda install package-name
```

Comment: I am still getting:```NotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to a required path.
  path: /home/iai/anaconda3/pkgs/cache/4ea078d6.json
  uid: 1004
  gid: 1004

If you feel that permissions on this path are set incorrectly, you can manually
change them by executing

  $ sudo chown 1004:1004 /home/iai/anaconda3/pkgs/cache/4ea078d6.json

In general, it's not advisable to use 'sudo conda'.```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by Anaconda GUI.

1. Go to environments tab.
2. select your preferred environment Right click and open in cmd .
3. Then install geopandas package from cmd window.

This way you will be isolating your package installation from root environment.